# How to compare and get data between given dates in mongodb?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, date, datetime, pymongo

I need to get the data from MongoDB between two given dates. The same mongo db query is working for ( yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms ) format but it is not working for ( dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss) format.

**Sample Data in DB**

```
{
"name":"user1",
"Value":"Success",
"Date": "02-06-2020 00:00:00",
"Status":"available",
"Updated_on":"2021-01-09 00:00:00.0000"
}
```

**Python:**

```
start_date = "02-06-2020 00:00:00"
end_date = "11-06-2020 10:16:41"

data = list(db.collection.find({"Date":{"gte":start_date,"Slte":end_date},"Value":"Success"},{'_id':False,"Date":1,"name":1,"Value":1}))
print(data)
```

I need to get the data based on the "Date" field.
The problem is it is giving extra data than the start_date and end_date.

Example: if my start_date is "02-06-2020 00:00:00"and end_date is "11-06-2020 10:16:41", it is giving data from "02-04-2020 00:00:00" to "11-06-2020 10:16:41"

Any idea to achieve this and please explain why it is not taking dates correctly.

Comment: **Never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw (and you use even different formats). Store proper `Date` objects then you can query them.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit To resolve such flaws, `dateFromString` added? Is it?

Comment: @Gibbs yes, if it is part of a migration. Using it only within the query would be just an ugly workaround.